# Aligning the bootstrap column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to give equal spaces on all sides for below image? The leftside of margin is lesser than the rightside and the bottom spaces are more. So, without manually changing the column with offset values, is there another possibility?

```css
.row{
    margin-top: 150px;
    margin-left: 30px;
}

#one{

    background-color:lavender; 
    width:330px; 
    height:250px; 
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#two{
    background-color:lavenderblush; 
    width:330px; 
    height:250px; 
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#three{
    background-color:lavender; 
    width:330px; 
    height:250px; 
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  

    <div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-4 ">
     <div class="col-md-12" id="one" >
        Some Content.. 
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 ">
     <div class="col-md-12" id="two">
        Some Second Content.. 
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="col-md-12" id="three">
        Some Second Content.. 
     </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="col-md-12" id="one" >
        Some Content.. 
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="col-md-12" id="two">
        Some Second Content.. 
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="col-md-12" id="three">
        Some Second Content.. 
     </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="col-md-12" id="one" >
        Some Content.. 
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="col-md-12" id="two">
        Some Second Content.. 
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="col-md-12" id="three">
        Some Second Content.. 
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
    
  </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Why don't you try padding and let the elements decide space among them based on the padding and margin...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases you shouldn't change the left/right margin on the `.row` because it's essential to [how the Bootstrap grid works](https://medium.com/wdstack/how-the-bootstrap-grid-really-works-471d7a089cfc). Also `col-*` shouldn't be contained directly in another `col-*`.

```
.row{
    margin-top: 150px;
}
```

Just use a centered div inside the columns..

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div id="one" class="center-block">
                Some Content..
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 ">
            <div id="two" class="center-block">
                Some Second Content..
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div id="three" class="center-block">
                Some Second Content..
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Demo on Codeply](http://www.codeply.com/go/qpKEId1oaW)

Answer (score 0):

This might help you
[Codepen link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dNByJM?editors=1100)

Do this for all of them.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 ">
    <div id="one" >
      Some Content.. 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 ">
    <div id="two">
      Some Second Content.. 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div id="three">
      Some Second Content.. 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#three{
  background-color:lavender; 
  width:100%; 
  height:250px; 
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: auto;
}
```